# SharePoint 2019 File Share Crawling and opening results (i.e. the "file://" protocol)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search

I'm curious to know if people are still using SharePoint to crawl your file shares.

And if so, what are organisations like yourselves (with Chrome/Edge as their default browser) doing to handle the issue that those Chromium browsers will not open hyperlinks using the "file://" protocol (e.g. "file://file-share-server/path/to/document.docx").